# How to manage jQueryUI dialog stack order or create "always on top" dialogs

Tags: jquery-ui

Is there a best known strategy to manage dialog "stacking order" or create dialogs that are "always on top"?

It seems that whenever you use .dialog() to create a second dialog, it sets the zindex to be "one more than the previous zindex". That's fine most of the time, but if the application has already popped up a "modal dialog" where you don't want anything else to come up on top, then it's a problem. Most of the time a user can't trigger anything because the modal dialog is likely blocking other UI elements. But, in my case there are asynch events occurring and I don't want that second dialog to popup over the modal dialog. I want it to popup under it.

I would imagine there are other cases where it was desirable to have the dialog stacking order follow some predefined "priority". For example, in MS Windows development they have long had the concept of an "always on top" window property. Conceptually, that seems like what I need.

Has anyone had a similar need and found a good solution?

Answer (score 0):

> but, in my case there are asynch events occurring and I don't want that second dialog to popup over the modal dialog. I want it to popup under it.

Well, jquery  and most web stuff is async, so there might be some UI blocking, but it is at the UI level - not at the code level. And thus you can as the developer still code out other events and run code. So, you could pop the first one, and then the 2nd one in code - your code will not be blocked or prevent you from doing this.

> But, in my case there are async events occurring and I don't want that second dialog to popup over the modal dialog. I want it to popup under it.

Do you really want that order of code? I would suggest that you ONLY popup the dialog that supposed to be under the current dialog AFTER you close the current dialog.

In other words, in the on close event of the current dialog, you THEN pop up the dialog you wanted to display under.  One can consider messing around with z-index stuff, but I would not go down that road, since changes to zindex etc. is likely to blow up lots of existing code. (don't mess with zindex unless you REALLY have no other choice). You don't want to manage the zindex stuff, but manage this by the order YOU the developer launches the boxes.

So, you can rather easy attach a event stub to the close event of that current dialog and THEN popup what you wanted underneath.  Or you can even attach code to the current dialog if you place buttons in that dialog.

Such a button will:

simply close the current dialog when pressed;
eg:

```
  $('#mydiv').dialog('close');
  ' code here to launch that dialog you wanted underneath.
```

Then launch that dialog you wanted to display underneath.

But it would better to use the close event of the dialog, and have it fire off your code +  display of that 2nd dialog you wanted underneath. (since the code stubs to launch the dialog, and the code stub to launch the 2nd would be separate stubs - so you attaching a event to the close of the dialog - not having code  close + launch the 2nd dialog in the same routine.

The other approach would be to load the first dialog, and the load the 2nd one that displays on top. Again, you thus load a dialog, then load more dialogs and so on down the line. This way you really never worry about the order, or even if previous dialogs are open or in use.

My spider sense?
Don't load the dialog under.
Show the current, and then you have several chances (and events) to now display the dialog underneath BY LOADING it AFTER you close the current dialog. Unless that content has a lot of data/pictures etc., then what the user sees when:

Close a dialog to see the one under
or
Close a dialog and display the dialog that you want.

I doubt performance will really change what the user sees and feels.

So, my best suggest is to display/load/show that dialog under AFTER you close the dialog we are in/on/viewing/using/looking at.